# Merge image and save it on the server

Tags: php, merge

I have a question about how to merge images and save it on the server.
I take this code from http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/03/22/interactive-image-vamp-up-with-jquery-css3-and-php/ , it's a really cool tutorial, but the last part don't say how create an a temporal image on the server, for the people send it to they friends.

This is the php code:

```
<?php
$res = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsondata']), true);
/* get data */
$count_images = count($res['images']);
/* the background image is the first one */
$background     = $res['images'][0]['src'];
$photo1         = imagecreatefromjpeg($background);
$foto1W         = imagesx($photo1);
$foto1H         = imagesy($photo1);
$photoFrameW    = $res['images'][0]['width'];
$photoFrameH    = $res['images'][0]['height'];
$photoFrame     = imagecreatetruecolor($photoFrameW,$photoFrameH);
imagecopyresampled($photoFrame, $photo1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $photoFrameW, $photoFrameH, $foto1W, $foto1H);

/* the other images */
for($i = 1; $i < $count_images; ++$i){
    $insert         = $res['images'][$i]['src'];
    $photoFrame2Rotation = (180-$res['images'][$i]['rotation']) + 180;

    $photo2         = imagecreatefrompng($insert);

    $foto2W         = imagesx($photo2);
    $foto2H         = imagesy($photo2);
    $photoFrame2W   = $res['images'][$i]['width'];
    $photoFrame2H   = $res['images'][$i]['height'];

    $photoFrame2TOP = $res['images'][$i]['top'];
    $photoFrame2LEFT= $res['images'][$i]['left'];

    $photoFrame2    = imagecreatetruecolor($photoFrame2W,$photoFrame2H);
    $trans_colour   = imagecolorallocatealpha($photoFrame2, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($photoFrame2, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

    imagecopyresampled($photoFrame2, $photo2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $photoFrame2W, $photoFrame2H, $foto2W, $foto2H);

    $photoFrame2    = imagerotate($photoFrame2,$photoFrame2Rotation, -1,0);
    /*after rotating calculate the difference of new height/width with the one before*/
    $extraTop       =(imagesy($photoFrame2)-$photoFrame2H)/2;
    $extraLeft      =(imagesx($photoFrame2)-$photoFrame2W)/2;

    imagecopy($photoFrame, $photoFrame2,$photoFrame2LEFT-$extraLeft, $photoFrame2TOP-$extraTop, 0, 0, imagesx($photoFrame2), imagesy($photoFrame2));    
}
// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($photoFrame, $targetfile); 
imagedestroy($photoFrame);

?>
```

Comment: The code saves the generated image to the file specified in variable `$targetfile`.

Comment: So $targetfile is the final image?

Comment: The final image appears to be `$photoFrame` but due to the `imagejpeg($photoFrame, $targetfile)` the image is actually written to the file, whose name is stored in `$targetfile`. At some point you must have specified what this variable contains or else you would get an error.

Comment: So what I can do? Where I can find a tutorial or something?